# hubspot to IIS with new domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Marketing has decided they no longer want to use hubspot for a blog. They now want to host internally.
How do I make the following changes
blog.domainname.com/blogname point to www.domainname.com/blogs/similarblogname

www.domainname.com is already established, but there is no subdomain blog.domainname.com.  In order to do the URL Rewrite do I have to create the blog.domainname site structure and then forward over to the subfolder view in IIS via URL Rewrite. I have 50 blog sites that need to be repointed to their new home and I'm trying to think of the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if I correctly catch what you're trying to do, you'll need to define a internal redirection rule that refers the new URL pattern using the old pattern.

So, first install the **URL Rewriter** module in the IIS server and define a pattern that will map and extract the appropriate parts to compose the new URL to refer your resources in your web server structure.

### Defining a pattern

In the Pattern text box, define the following string:

```
^blog.yourdomain.com/([_0-9a-z-]+)
```

This string is a regular expression that specifies that the pattern will match any URL string that meets the following conditions:

1. Starts with the sequence of characters "blog.yourdomain.com/".
2. Contains one or more alphanumeric or "_" or "-" characters after the first slash ("/").

The parts of the regular expression within those parentheses create capture groups, which can be later referenced in the action.

### Defining an action

Choose the Rewrite **Action type** as the URL we are creating is supposed to rewrite the URL that is listed in the **Action** group box.

In the **Rewrite URL** text box, enter the following string:

```
www.yourdomain.com/blog/{R:1}
```

We hope this helps you in the task!

You can get more detailed information on the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Comment: No matter what I do I keep getting - Server Error in '/' Application.

Run-time Error.    When I look in the IIS logs it appears that that the /{R:1} name is being changed but I'm not getting sub-folder should be /blog/{R:1}

Comment: Does it prepends your domain before the {R:1} substituted part? Does your domain have 'www' mapping for web server?